# Как составить цикл? (управление кроликом на Google Doodles)

Tags: алгоритм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо реализовать алгоритм (желательно рекурсивный) на платформе Google Doodles. Мне нужно, чтобы кролик собрал все морковки по самому кратчайшему пути.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте еще один поворот и оберните все свои команды еще во внешний цикл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: длинно) http://joxi.ru/n2YO70eFoleKwr

Comment: @pavel долго :)